# How to limit file to be accessed only from server?

Tags: c#, iis

I need a C# code that will allow the file to be accessed only if the server that my app is on will send request to that file. If user from browser tries to access it, it shall give out "403 Forbidden" error message.

Thanks upfront.

Comment: asp.net? your own web server?

Comment: so localhost can access the file through browser but remotely cannot... what is the objective here btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable external access to file in local web.config file located in directory with restricted files. Similar approach used in ASP.MET MVC Views folder.

**Local web.config**

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the file is in a location on the filesystem that isn't accessible to IIS (if using the default directory: outside of *wwwroot*), then use C# to access the file.

This way they cannot browse to it.

Comment: He wants to access the file through the browser. On the server itself that should work, on any other client an error message should appear.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar He never says anything about his app needing the file accessible through the browser.

Comment: Oh, right - is misread the question... Sorry to interrupt :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's for IIS, have a look at [ipSecurity Element [IIS Settings Schema]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691353%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">

   <clear/>

   <!-- Allow only requests from the local machine. -->
   <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/> 

</ipSecurity>
```